# Are there any tips for improving driving skills in racing games using an analog stick controller?

Tags: controllers

I enjoy console racing games, but not really enough to invest in a steering wheel controller and pedals.

That being said, when I'm using the analog sticks to steer, I don't ever feel like I can hold the stick at just the right position to make a smooth and accurate turn and/or drift. Rather, I find myself constantly tapping the analog stick left and right to make minor adjustments. I'm pretty sure that's not the best way, but I really haven't found any other method that feels quite right and still in control. I'm just wondering if anyone had any tips for better control and accuracy using the analog sticks.

I've seen accessories to extend the control sticks for FPS games (Something like [Speed Freek](http://www.kontrolfreek.com/Game-Controller-Accessories/KontrolFreek-Speed-Freek.asp), for example), but I'm not sure if those would apply in a case like this or not. Something like an accessory like that isn't entirely out of the question if it could be helpful for other things as well and relatively inexpensive.

I'm assuming this could be pretty general advice as most racing games I've encountered on the Xbox 360 and PS3 both use a typical left analog stick to steer and a trigger or button to accelerate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the things I liked most about some of the Gran Turismo games is that they let you use both Playstation analog sticks (the left to steer, and the right for forward and reverse acceleration). I'm not sure if the games you're playing have an option for that, but I'd try it and practice that way for a bit. I find that it not only centers your hands better on the controller (i.e. your right hand isn't moving the left stick when you hit the accelerate button a bit too hard), but that acceleration and braking are much, much smoother.

It might not be the same problem, but most of my turning problems were solved by smoother acceleration and braking into the turns, not by the actual steering itself. Give it a shot if you have the option.

Other than that suggestion, try to practice not tapping the sticks so much, but keeping pressure on them at all times. When you start to initiate a turn, give yourself enough time to decelerate and gradually and smoothly steer toward the straightest exit through the curve rather than hammering the stick at the last second. Knowing the course really helps here, since your hands will start to remember what they're supposed to do at any given point.

I suppose that's pretty general, but I hope there's something useful in there for ya.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I have a hard time with keep pressure on them at all times I guess is my problem. Found the Speed Freek product, wondering if they may help. I suppose 9.99 is worth finding out maybe.

Comment: It's certainly possible; I'm always a bit skeptical about add-ons (especially ones that claim to scientifically test and don't provide any details), but most of the reviews seem positive and 9.99 isn't exactly a bank-breaker if it turns out you don't like them.